# Nodejs: Wait for a promise to get resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this code, variables adminName and adminPassword should get values before the execution of if statements. But if statements are executing before the then handler function. thats why the validation not working.

```
function validateAdminLogin()
{

var adminName="";
var adminPassword="";   

var isValid=true;

var UserDAO = require('./js/DAO/UserDAO');  
var wait=require('wait.for-es6');
var admin=document.getElementById("adminform").elements.namedItem("username").value;
var adminPwd=document.getElementById("adminform").elements.namedItem("pwd").value;




    UserDAO.getAdminCredentials().then(function(rows){

    adminName= rows.username;
    adminPassword=rows.password;

    alert(admin+"----"+adminName);

    },function(error){
    alert(error);
    console.log(error);
    });



    //alert(admin+"-------"+adminName);

if(admin!==adminName) 
{
alert("Invalid username");
isValid=false;
}


if(adminPwd!==adminPassword) 
{
alert("Invalid password");
isValid=false;
} 

return isValid;
}
```

---

I'm also including the code in which I've written the promise.

```
getAdminCredentials: function()
{
    var deferred = q.defer(); 

    $query =  "SELECT * FROM `user` where type='administrator' ";

    connection.connect(function(err) {

        if(err){
            console.log(err.code);
            console.log(err.fatal);
        }

     // console.log("Successfully connected.");
    });

    connection.query($query, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err){
            console.log("An error ocurred performing the query.");
            console.log(err);
            deferred.reject(err);
            return;
        }
        else
            {
             console.log("Query succesfully executed");
            userDTO.setUserId(rows[0].user_id);
           userDTO.setUsername(rows[0].username);
           userDTO.setPassword(rows[0].password);

           deferred.resolve(userDTO);

            }



    }); 


    return deferred.promise;

    connection.end();
}
```

How do I deal with this asynchronous nature of nodejs? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to put your if statement inside the then() statement.

Everything that needs the credentials should be put in the then or in other following then().
For example, you might return your promise:

```
return UserDAO.getAdminCredentials().then(function(rows){ ...
```

and when calling your function add a then() to it:

```
validateAdminLogin().then( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your `validateAdminLogin` function like this:

```
function validateAdminLogin() {
    var UserDAO = require('./js/DAO/UserDAO');
    var wait = require('wait.for-es6');
    var admin = document.getElementById("adminform").elements.namedItem("username").value;
    var adminPwd = document.getElementById("adminform").elements.namedItem("pwd").value;

    // return a promise which will be resolved with a bool indicating the "valid" status
    // the promise can reject when there was an error
    return UserDAO.getAdminCredentials().then(function(rows) {
        var adminName = rows.username;
        var adminPassword = rows.password;

       if (admin !== adminName) {
           alert("Invalid username");
           return false
       }

       if (adminPwd !== adminPassword) {
           alert("Invalid password");
           return false
       }

       return true
   }, function(error) {
       console.log(error);
   });
}
```

You'll have to handle your function call somewhat different because it doesn't return the bool immediately. You're call site would look like this:

```
validateAdminLogin().then(function (isValid) {
    // handle the "isValid" bool
}, function (error) {
    // handle the error...
});
```

It **isn't** possible to synchronize a asynchronous action in node.js.

Comment: You can't call it like this from HTML but you could add an additional handler to handle the (Event)?. I guess that you have something like an HTML Form so you can add an event listener to the form to handle the "[submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit)" event.

Comment: Its not working. The script gets executed as soon as the page loads. And when I add event.preventDefault() everything works fine but because of preventDefault(),the form is not submitted.

Comment: @PranjaliSoni you can call the [`HTMLForm.submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method to submit the form after you've validated the values. But you need to set a flag so that you don't run the validation again.